# Can someone help me with this karel code?

Tags: java, computer-science

```
import kareltherobot.*;
public class main
{
    public static Robot ho;
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Robot ho = new Robot(1, 1, Directions.East, 10000);
        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
            ho.putBeeper();
            ho.move();
        }
        }
    static
    {
        World.reset();
        World.setVisible(true);
        World.setSize(100, 100);
        World.setDelay(2);
    }
}
```

Here is my code for karel the robot. I'm taking Java in high school and suck at it, I am trying to make karel go through a 100 by 100 world and put beepers on every square, but I don't know how to do this.

[Karel API](http://www.csis.pace.edu/~bergin/KarelJava2ed/KJRdocs/index.html):
the move command moves the robot one space in the direction it's facing.
The put beeper command places a beeper in that space it is currently in.

Comment: Does `move()` just arbitrarily move the robot or what?

Comment: it moves the robot one space forward in the direction it's facing @ChiefTwoPencils

Comment: OK, well then we should be able to agree the robot cannot fill a 100x100 world going only one direction. Think about it like a chess board which should look like a 2d array which should then give you an idea of what is needed.

Comment: so I can make it turn left and spiral or I can make it zigzag horizontally, but I don't know how to make the forloops @ChiefTwoPencils

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the 2d array, that is too advanced. I remember karel is the first thing you learn in compsci. If I remember correctly, don't they have a turnleft or turnright method?You could make it move, put beepers, and then turn.